# How to automatically generate .gitsubmodules from existing directory structure?

Tags: git, submodule

I have a directory in which different sub-directories are github repos from many places. Now I want to upload them in another git repo. Is there anyway to generate `.gitmodules` for this parent repo. Or do I have to manually add each subdirectory information in `.gitmodules`.